# python class empty dataframe

Tags: python, oop

The purpose of this script is:

•   Read a group of csv files.

•   Scrape the date and extract some features out of it.

•   Merge these csv files into a single data frame.

•   Import the final data frame into another class and print it.

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os


class DataSource:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dfs = []
        self.final = pd.DataFrame()
        self.names = ['Date', 'Time', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'Volume']
        self.directory = os.chdir(r"C:\Users\Sayed\Desktop\forex")

    def merge(self):
        for file in os.listdir(self.directory):
            df = pd.read_csv(file, names=self.names,
                             parse_dates={'Release Date': ['Date', 'Time']})
            self.dfs.append(df)

        self.final = pd.concat(self.dfs, axis=0)
        self.final = self.final[['Release Date', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close']]
        print(self.final.head())
        return self.final


class test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.df = DataSource().final

    def print(self):
        return print(self.df)


x = test()
x.print()
```

Here is the output:

```
Empty DataFrame

Columns: []

Index: []
```

Comment: It never calls `merge`.

Answer (score 1):

You should call function to create something. Try this one.

```
class test():
def __init__(self):
    self.df = DataSource(). merge()
```